# Remove Defect from Iteration ClearQuest API

Tags: perl, clearquest

There can multiple defects attached to an iteration.How can I remove a particular defect from iteration using ClearQuest Perl API?

```
$bfSession = CQSession::Build();
$bfSession->UserLogon($userID,$passwd,$dbname,$dbset);

#Get iteration Entity
$iterationEntity = $bfSession->GetEntity("tmiteration", $iteration);

#Now to add defect to Iteration i can do the following
$bfSession->EditEntity($iterationEntity, "modify");
$result = $iterationEntity->AddFieldValue("Defects", $defect);
$valResult = $iterationEntity->Validate();

if($valResult eq "")
    {
        $iterationEntity->Commit();
    }
    else
    {
        $iterationEntity->Revert();
    }
```

Just like AddFieldValue Is there is any API to remove defects from iteration?

EDIT: I was not able to find such API in IBM [ClearQuest](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/topics/default_topic.htm) documention

Comment: You will have to refer to the documentation of ClearQuest. Asking for a link to documentation is off-topic on Stack Overflow unfortunately.

Comment: @simbabque Ok... I went through the documentation but so far no luck...I am trying couple of other things to see if it solves my case...
Just in case if i am able to find answer of above question, can i answer it here

Comment: Maybe include a link to the documentation in the question. Others might have more luck in spotting the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [DeleteFieldValue](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH5A_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/topics/r_entity_delfldval.htm) API to Remove Child records from parent records.

```
$bfSession->EditEntity($IterationEntity, "modify");
$result = $IterationEntity->DeleteFieldValue("Defects", $defectId);
```